# Detect webrequest coming from PWA on the server side

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm adding PWA support to a web app. I want to add a back-button to the interface for iOS when the app is used as a PWA but not when used in the old fashioned way in Safari (or another browser).

I know I can detect this via JS - so I could just show/hide the back-button at runtime, but I would like to know if there is any way to detect in **on the server-side** already (**apache/php**). I guess there will be more use-cases coming up to serve slightly different content.

I guess I could set a **cookie**, but I want to make sure there is nothing more easy/obvious to use, some new header for example.

Comment: As far as I know there is only the client side way with [`window.navigator.standalone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

Comment: Actually setting a cookie failed in my tests. The PWA and web shared cookies so the website was thinking its a PWA once the PWA was opened.

Answer (score 2):

Found one more way in the meantime to do it, apart from cookies. Sending a custom http header via a service worker.

### app.js

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {
    if(registration.active) {
        const sw = registration.active;
        sw.postMessage({
            'is_pwa': is_pwa()
        });
    }
});
```

### sw.js

```
var myHeader = new Headers(event.request.headers);
    if (is_pwa) {
        myHeader.append('ISPWA', is_pwa ? is_pwa : "");
    }
    var config = {
        headers: myHeader
    };
    if(navigator.onLine !== false) {
        event.respondWith(fetch(request).catch(function(error) {
            fetch(request, config).catch(function() {
            [...]
```

### php

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_ISPWA']);
```